# How to switch to a different Testinfra host mid-test?

Tags: testing, ansible, automated-tests, pytest, testinfra

I am trying to, within the same test, execute the code first on the machine A (aka The Host), make an assertion, then execute code on the machine B (aka The SNIC), make an assertion there, and then execute code on the machine A again.

Here is my PyTest testfile that uses Testinfra and Ansible:

```py
import pytest
import basic_io

testinfra_hosts = ["ansible://host"]


###################################################
# test_virtio_blk_exposed is executed on The Host #
###################################################

@pytest.mark.dependency(name="virtio_blk_exposed")
def test_virtio_blk_exposed(configure_virtio_blk_zero_copy_fixture, host, load_virtio_modules,
                            get_virtio_blk_devices):
    """
    Verify that at least one virtio device is exposed on host
    """
    print(get_virtio_blk_devices)
    assert len(get_virtio_blk_devices) > 0


###########################################################
# The commented out code below should execute on The SNIC #
###########################################################

# cmd = host.run("/path/to/binary --parameter=value")
#    assert cmd.rc == 0


################################################
# test_test_fio_verify is executed on The Host #
################################################

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["virtio_blk_exposed"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("rw", ["randrw"])
def test_fio_verify(configure_virtio_blk_zero_copy_fixture,
                    host, load_virtio_modules,
                    get_virtio_blk_devices, rw):
    """
    Test fio with verify option on every virtio device
    """
    target_dev = get_virtio_blk_devices[-1]
    basic_io.run_fio_verify_test(host, "/dev/{}".format(target_dev), rw)
```

Here's a relevant part of my Ansible inventory:

```
all:
  children:
    snic_grp:
      hosts: { hostname-snic.domain.zone }
    host:
      hosts: { hostname.domain.zone }
```

Now, the [Testinfra documentation](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/invocation.html) vaguely mentions that I can use multiple hosts at once. Thus, I can replace this line:

```
testinfra_hosts = ["ansible://host"]
```

with this:

```
testinfra_hosts = ["ansible://host", "ansible://snic_grp"]
```

However, it does not explain how to switch to the second testinfra host and back to the first one in the middle of the test.
And that is exactly my question. That's what I'm trying to do but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.